# How to Load Function in new Powershell.exe Console

Tags: powershell

I have a function (function1) which requires sta mode. I'd like tocall this function from a non sta mode poshconsole. This works when i have function1 in my Profile

```
$command = "function1 'MyArguments'"
powershell -sta -command $command
```

But how can i do this when i have the function1 not in the profile and i call

```
powershell -sta -noprofile -command $command
```

Can i execute multiple commands with a powershell.exe call? Or can i handover a customprofilepath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate multiple commands with a semicolon (;) for example, dot source your script containing your function, then call the function:

```
powershell -sta -noprofile -command ". c:\functions.ps1 ; function1 'MyArguments'"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways how to deal with STA:

- [Single Threaded Apartment in PowerShell V1](http://get-powershell.com/2008/11/06/single-threaded-apartment-in-powershell-v1/comment-page-1/)
- [Asynchronicity in PowerShell](http://cjoprey.blog.com/2009/08/17/asynchronicity-in-powershell/)
- [Thread.ApartmentState and PowerShell Execution Thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/03/23/thread-apartmentstate-and-powershell-execution-thread.aspx)

In case you will call powershell.exe (because it is obviously easier), you can first load your script with the function and then execute `function1 'My arguments'`

```
powershell -sta -noprofile -command '<pathToYourScript>.ps1; function1 args'
```

I tried to use `-file` parameter and `-command` argument together, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) you can use Invoke-Apartment e.g.:

```
PS> Invoke-Apartment -Apartment STA `
                     -Expr {[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ApartmentState}
STA
```